# definition for data types in assembly language

Tags: assembly

I have to give a concret definition for data types in assembly language.
And to give example of declaration using variable (with and without initialization) for different kind of data types.

Data types are: byte,word,d-word.
And example I can say:

```
 a db 10
 b dw 128 (here I can write b db 128?)
 c dd 2AFBH
```

This are examples with initialization, but how I write without initialization?

Comment: It depends which assembler you are using. Check the manual.

Comment: 8086 assembly language

Comment: That's not an assembler. An assembler would be TASM or NASM or GAS or ML. Check the manual for the assembler you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Many assemblers use a **?** like `myVar db ?` to clearly show you don't care about the initialization value. But even then most of the time the space will be filled with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

assembly language is defined by the assembler, the program that converts the ascii program into machine code.  And there are no standards, each assembler can and often does choose its own directives to define data items that are not instructions.  the instructions themselves can vary from one assembler to the other to be sure, it is only the machine code for a particular instruction set that has to conform to some definition.